# IIS 7 Redirect using conditions

Tags: regex, iis, redirect

I asked this question previously I think poorly - so here in a nutshell...

I have a chinese and australian site

First Redirect is good

```
http://mycompany.com/myproduct --> http://mycompany.com/products/myproduct
```

I also need this

```
http://mycompany.com/cn/myproduct --> http://mycompany.com/cn/products/myproduct
```

this expression matches the 1st and 2nd
    ^(cn|com)/myproduct/?

question is - under the action panel , what is the format of the Redirect Url to satisfy both?

something like 
Redirect Url: {R:0}/products/myproduct  (this doesnt work..just for illustration)

cheers!

EDIT:

If this helps - here's the rule im having problems with in web.config

```
            <rule name="myproduct" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(cn|com)/myproduct/?" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/products/myproduct" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<rules>
   <rule name="myproduct" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^([^/]{2,3}/)?myproduct(/$|$)" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}products/myproduct" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..no go when trying this. I used ^(cn|com)/myproduct/? to match, but both conditions (cn/myproduct and com/myproduct) redirect to com/products/myproduct

Comment: I've updated now back at a computer. It would actually be easier break these into 2 separate rules, but this should work.