# How to run specific pages on https

Tags: asp.net, appharbor

I have used a rule to redirect pages to https.The following is the rule in web.config:

```
  <rules>

      <rule name="HTTPs Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{ALL_HTTP}" matchType="Pattern"
               pattern="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO:https" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />            
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
  </rewrite>
```

This rule is redirecting all the pages to https but I want to redirect some pages of my application like if I have two pages test.aspx and test1.aspx then i want to redirect test.aspx to https and test1.aspx to http.
How it will be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either elaborate on the url regex your already have in the `match` element ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304689/iis-7-redirect-using-conditions)) or you can add [additional conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678956/iis-url-rewrite-rule-redirect-with-mask).